# Manual installation of Magento extension turns every file into a folder

Tags: magento

I am completely baffled by this.  I packaged up an extension and manually installed it on a fresh Magento instance. (Both the packaging and installing machine were running Magento 1.7).    The installation went smoothly,  except every single file I installed was turned into a folder, named after the file.   Every single file.  Has anyone run into this?  Could it be a Magento bug?

Comment: I honestly have never seen this, but I prefer to manually install my plugins and modules just to be sure.  Is there any way for you to download the package in a `ZIP`,`TAR.GZ`,`RAR` etc format?  That you could expand the package and manually move the `PHP`, `PHTML` and `XML` files to the correct directory maintaining their correct formatting??

Comment: Yeah that would work.   But I'm trying to get this working through the default Magento functionality.     This guy is having the same problem as me,  and his is recent as well. He doesn't have an answer yet either:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471304/magento-making-folder-instead-of-file-when-new-extension-insatll

Answer (score 4):

I used to see this problem when I manually created a `tar` archive to use as a Magento Connect archive.  Unfortunately, I don't have a solution, but here's what I understand about the problem.

While Magento Connect `tgz` packages are technically gzip compressed tar archives — the code that creates and extracts these archives in **not** the standard *nix `tar` tool.  Instead, Magento implemented its own packing and unpacking tar code for Magento Connect

```
downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Tar.php
```

Unfortunately, this packing and unpacking code hasn't been robustly tested across operating systems or against tar archives created with standard *nix tools. My problem with this code was archives created on my Mac OS system via `tar` wouldn't unpack correctly with Magento Connect's code on a system running linux.

Hard to track down, hard to report, hard to reproduce means hard to fix.

These directories are being created when Magento Connect unpacks the `tgz` file.  I'm be 99% sure your directories are being created by this bit of code

```
#File: downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Tar.php
if (in_array($header['type'], array("0",chr(0), ''))) {

    if(!file_exists($dirname)) {
        $mkdirResult = @mkdir($dirname, 0777, true);

        if (false === $mkdirResult) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to create directory ' . $dirname);
        }
    }

    $this->_extractAndWriteFile($header, $currentFile);
    $list[] = $currentFile;

} elseif ($header['type'] == '5') {

    if(!file_exists($dirname)) {
        $mkdirResult = @mkdir($currentFile, $header['mode'], true);

        if (false === $mkdirResult) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('Failed to create directory ' . $currentFile);
        }
    }
    $list[] = $currentFile . DS;
```

These are the two locations where Magento unpacks the archives and creates a folder.  For some reason, there's a certain condition on your two systems where the data is being packed, or unpacked, incorrectly in/out of the archive file.  Try un-archiving the `tgz` file manually with a command line tool or your operating system's built in un-archive program.  If weird things happen then at least you know it's the packing code that's the problem.

It's definitely a bug, and while I'd report it, the only "solution" would be to not create your archive on your local machine (which I realize is an awful solution, but *Ours is not to question why* and all that)

Comment: Thank you for the information!   I'm using the built-in Magento packager,  and again the built-in Magento package uploader to install.   This seems to be a major bug.  How do people who sell extensions get around it?

Comment: @swl1020 Ah, I thought by "manually install" you meant not using the Connect admin.  I added some additional information to help you debug.  Regardless, while "major when you encounter it", this bug doesn't seem to occur frequently, so it ends up not being that major to the platform.  For Commerce Bug (the debugging extension I sell) I create the package on a server I know creates good packages, and not on my local machine. I suspect most extension developers don't run into the problem, and if they do they do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been present since 1.7, due to an if comparison never evaluating to false when reading the `@././LongLink` header. I answered it more on this question:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/long-file-names-and-magento-connect-extension-packager/45187#45187

Comment: this is exactly my issue: the problem comes when Magento Connect decompress the archive ...

Comment: Correct, this bug is only present on the tar extraction side, have a look at the link I posted and the subsequent blog post it should completely resolve your issue

Comment: I just had this while trying to install a Connect extension in 1.9.2CE! Will they ever fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that issue happening when packing a Magento Extension on OS X that is linked (modman) into magento folders. Folder creation only occured on Windows systems.

Might that happen here too?

Rico

Comment: The packaging system is an Amazon Web Server.  The unpackaging system is running Windows 7

Comment: The files that were created as folders: Were they hard/symlinked and then packed?

Comment: what do you mean?  Like,  when I packed it up using the Magento packager?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered it, when for some reason my plugin file was set with suffix .gz
so it was plugin.tgz.gz
unzip it to plugin.tgz solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because of PHP version. I faced the same issue while installing extension on Magento 1.8.1 , but I found a fix by changing _getFormatParseHeader() function in /downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Tar.php file.

Originally the function was :

```
protected static final function _getFormatParseHeader()
{
    return 'a100name/a8mode/a8uid/a8gid/a12size/a12mtime/a8checksum/a1type/a100symlink/a6magic/a2version/'
        . 'a32uname/a32gname/a8devmajor/a8devminor/a155prefix/a12closer';
}
```

I changed it to :

```
protected static final function _getFormatParseHeader()
{
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.0', '<') === true) {
        return 'a100name/a8mode/a8uid/a8gid/a12size/a12mtime/a8checksum/a1type/a100symlink/a6magic/a2version/'
        . 'a32uname/a32gname/a8devmajor/a8devminor/a155prefix/a12closer';
    }
    return 'Z100name/Z8mode/Z8uid/Z8gid/Z12size/Z12mtime/Z8checksum/Z1type/Z100symlink/Z6magic/Z2version/'
        . 'Z32uname/Z32gname/Z8devmajor/Z8devminor/Z155prefix/Z12closer';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really nasty bug.

For me it renaming my manually packed file from `*.tar.gz` to `*.tgz` solved it.

At least it worked on my ubuntu 15.04

Tested with magento 1.8

Answer (score -1):

it's more likely that you choose the wrong path when adding content to your extension.

For me the bug happened when I added (non existing) files from layout/base instead from layout/base/default.